# Can SMS with multiple parts have different results per part

Tags: smpp

New to SMPP. From what I understand, to send multi-part messages, you'll have to do multiple `submit_sm` requests (one for each part). You'll also have to specify the UDH values appropriately to specify that each request is for the same SMS.

In that case, is it possible for the parts to have different results? For example, one part is successfully delivered and another part failed?

Answer (score 0):

> In that case, is it possible for the parts to have different results?
> For example, one part is successfully delivered and another part
> failed?

Yes. The smpp client submits many submit_sm with relative UDH headers, and the smpp server / SMSC will concatenate the relative parts to one sms to the device. One part may fail to be delivered to the SMSC due to any reason - for the same reasons as for a 1-part submit_sm (for ex. full queue on SMSC, improper length of submit_sm, ...). If finally the truncated sms message will be delivered to the device from SMSC - due to a failure of a part - depends on SMSC setup.

Answer (score 0):

Depends how the SMSC is configurated,
Mainly, the SMSC forward in SS7 (FwdMT) to the MSC, this one can refuse the FwdMT or relay the phone acknowledgement.

For an example, the phone could be busy by recieving couple of SMS at the same time,
One FwdMT could be ack'ed by GSM error 31 (BUSY), if there is no str&fwd on this SMSC, the corresponding SUBMIT_SM wil be ack'ed in error,

If the SMSC supports the payload parameter, you could send the segmented SMS in one SUBMIT_SM via this payload parameter,
But it depends of SMSC configuration